# Under the hood of an integration tests with spring, application context manipulation

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, testing, junit

I know in the context of integration test on a spring application we can use, among others annotations:

- `@MockBean`
  To add mock objects to the Spring application context. The mock will replace any existing bean of the same type in the application context.
- `@Autowired`
  Can be used to inject a bean from the context

This is all very handy and nice but I don't understand how can this happens / how this is implemented.

In my understanding we can test software that runs a **tomcat server** in its own process, when the server spins up **spring** will create and wire up all the beans we defined, the so called **application context**.

How can the **application context** be manipulated from another process, the **Junit** process we are running the tests from ?

How can we look up beans from there with `@Autowired` and vice versa create beans with `@MockBean` ?

Looks like somehow the application context is somehow shared by two processes...

I am sure I am missing some piece of knowledge here, any pointing to resources to help me understand what's going on would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: +1, admit: don't know/never asked! my best contribution for now: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/main/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-test/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/test/mock/mockito/MockitoPostProcessor.java (+ "spring" + "spring test" knowledge)

Answer (score 0):

To keep things simple it is all done by the spring test integration library that you include in your project. When you launch your test annotated with a Spring annotation (`@SpringBootTest` or `@DataJpaTest` for example) they instruct junit to extends his engine to launch a test "flavour" of the spring boot context.

Then this context takes care of creating and autowiring "real" dependencies (like when you use the `@Autowired` annotation) or creating mocks and then autowire them instead of real dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Your Testframework runs the same process (i.e. in the same JVM) as your code under test, thus your tests and the testframework can interact without any restrictions (beside the standard jvm ones).
Additionally Spring provides extensions to e.g. JUnit, to provide easy access and manipulation to beans, context, configuration etc.

Comment: Thanks Kathrin, would it be appropriate or at least in the right direction to say that , in a way, the test class is yet another bean inside the spring context ?

Comment: No, I don't think so. But you can find out, just get the appliation context in your test and ask it for the beans it knows.